# netstat -na : udp and state established?

Tags: networking, udp, netstat

In an application (voip rtp media server), `netstat -na` on the server (172.16.226.3 bound to udp port 1286) gives the following line :

```
udp 0 0 172.16.226.3:1286 172.25.14.11:10000 ESTABLISHED
```

As an udp connection can not be really "established", it strikes me to see such a line. `netstat` documentation says that this field is used for tcp connection states, but I am sure that this really is an udp network flow. So : what does it means ? I know (wireshark dump) that my server sends back udp packets from `173.16.226.3:1286` to `172.25.14.11:10000`, but I don't see why it should matter...

Os is debian 6.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A UDP socket *can* be connected via the `connect(2)` system call, so that the socket will only accept packets from the named peer.

I expect this is the source of the `ESTABLISHED` column.

Comment: Indeed. In Python :
`import socket`
`sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )`
`sock.bind(("172.16.226.3",1086))`
`sock.connect(("172.25.14.1",36600))`
Gives :
`netstat -na | grep 36600`
`udp        0      0 172.16.226.3:1086       172.25.14.1:36600       ESTABLISHED`